# Cross-platform issue: getting LibUsbDotNet to work with same executable on Win/Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, cross-platform, libusb

I want to compile a C# app (VS2019, .NET 4.5, WinForms) on Windows 10 that uses the LibUsbDotNet library to print a list of connected USB devices. And I want that same exe to be able to be run on Ubuntu with the same result.

```
List<LibUsbRegistry> WinDevices = LibUsbRegistry.DeviceList;
foreach (LibUsbRegistry usbdev in WinDevices) {
   print_console(usbdev.FullName);
 }
```

So I added LibUsbDotNet package via NuGet, and made a small project with the above lines. Compiled, ran it and it did what was intended. So I copied that exe and the LibUsbDotNet.LibUsbDotNet.dll from the output directory onto the Ubuntu (20.10) PC, and ran it with Mono but it crashes:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateFile assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) LibUsbDotNet.Internal.Kernel32.CreateFile(string,LibUsbDotNet.Internal.NativeFileAccess,LibUsbDotNet.Internal.NativeFileShare,intptr,LibUsbDotNet.Internal.NativeFileMode,LibUsbDotNet.Internal.NativeFileFlag,intptr)
  at LibUsbDotNet.Internal.LibUsb.LibUsbDriverIO.OpenDevice (System.String deviceFileName) [0x00000] in <860e43ad45e14d59bf62e8efe5c0922a>:0 
  at LibUsbDotNet.LibUsb.LibUsbRegistry.get_DeviceList () [0x00011] in <860e43ad45e14d59bf62e8efe5c0922a>:0
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is the .dll the issue? I have been trying to do this for a few days without any luck. Any help would be freakin' awesome.